# Typo on Wikipedia? Dimension of $U(n)$

Tags: lie-groups

Let $U(n)$ denote the unitary group. That is,

$$ U(n) = \{A \in GL_n(\mathbb C)\mid A^\ast A = I\}$$

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group) states:

"The unitary group $U(n)$ is a real Lie group of dimension $n^2$. "

There seem to be two typos: one, unitary matrices are complex. So it should be a statement about complex Lie group. The other typo is $n^2$: $n^2$ is the dimension of $GL_n$ and $U(n)$ is a proper subgroup so clearly its dimension must be smaller than $n^2$.

> What's the dimension of $U(n)$?

Comment: No that is not a typo....

Comment: Try to check what happens when n=2..

Comment: $\Bbb C^n \cong \Bbb R^{2n}$...

Comment: It's the real dimension.

Comment: $U(n)$ is generated by the $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices. As a real linear space, the Hermitian matrices have a basis consists of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ real symmetric matrices and $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ imaginary antisymmetric matrices. This means the real dimension of $U(u)$ is $n^2$.

Comment: Start with $n=1$. $U(1) =\{z\ | \ |z|^2 = 1\}$.

Comment: @achillehui And what is its complex dimension?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The unitary group $U(n)$ is a *real* Lie group of $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$. We can forget about the complex structure on $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ and hence view it as a real Lie subgroup of (real) dimension $2 n^2$, which is greater than $\dim U(n) = n^2$.

Note, by the way, that $GL_+(n, \mathbb{R}) := \{A \in GL(n, \mathbb{R}) : \det A > 0\}$ is a proper subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ but $\dim GL_+(n, \mathbb{R}) = n^2 = \dim GL(n, \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't believe that $U(n)$ is not a (complex) subgroup of $GL_n$. Can you prove it? As far as I can tell $U(n)$ contains $I$ and is closed with respect to multiplication so it's a group. Also, it is the inverse image of the $|\det|$ map of $\{1\}$ so it's closed... or am I missing something?

Comment: It's certainly a subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$, but it's not a complex subgroup. The defining equation of $U(n)$ is $A^* A = I$, which in components is $\sum_{i = 1}^n \bar{a}_{ki} a_{kj}$, but these are not analytic conditions, because they involve conjugation. (For odd $n$, note that $\dim U(n) = n^2$ is odd, whereas every complex group has even real dimension.)

Comment: But in Tapp's book the definition of a  matrix group is given as any topologically closed subgroup of $GL_n$. What is your idea with "analytic condition" for a matrix group?

Comment: Again, $U(n)$ is a perfectly good *real* (matrix) Lie group, but it is not a *complex* Lie group: the latter requires that the group have a (1) complex-analytic manifold structure, and that (2) the multiplication and inversion operations on the group are holomorphic maps. This case is perhaps initially confusing because the underlying set of $U(n)$ is often taken to be a set of complex matrices, but this is an altogether separate condition.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful.

Comment: Doesn't $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ have complex dimension $n^2$? I thought its real dimension would be $2n^2$.

Comment: @DhanushGiriyan Here $n^2$ refers to the real dimension of $U(n)$, not of $GL(n, \Bbb C)$. I'll adjust the wording of the sentence to clarify.